# VBA Function Assignment Not Ending the Function

Tags: vba, function

### Details, details

I have various functions and subs in VBA as follows.

#### `IsBlank`

My first function, `IsBlank` checks a value: it does a `MsgBox` and returns `True` if that value is blank. If it's not blank, `IsBlank` returns `False`. This function gives the intended result.

#### `DoStuff1`

My next function -- let's call it `DoStuff1`-- should automatically return `False` if `IsBlank` is `True`. So I have at the very beginning:

```vb
If (IsBlank = True) Then
MsgBox "Yes, it does recognize there's a blank..." '<--It gets here...
DoStuff1 = False '<-- But this doesn't end the function.
'Exit Function <-- If I uncomment this, it works. But I shouldn't need it.
End If
```

The code following this `If` statement still runs.

#### `Dependent Procedures`

I have a number of sub procedures which use `DoStuff1`. At the beginning, I include:

```vb
If (DoStuff1 = False) Then
MsgBox "No, it doesn't get here..."
Exit Sub  '<--It doesn't exit
End If
```

Yet, these subs skip right over this, not seeing `DoStuff1` as `False`.

### To Sum It Up

Thus there are two undoubtedly interrelated problems:

1. `DoStuff1` does not end on the assignment to a value.
2. The sub referencing `DoStuff1` does not recognize `DoStuff1` as returning the value assigned.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong...? **Shouldn't assigning a value to a VBA function always end the function?**

*Note: Yes, I realize I could combine the functions, but I should be allowed to code in pretty pieces if I want to, right?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "**Shouldn't assigning a value to a VBA function always end the function?**"

***No***, assigning the function return value ***never*** ends the function.  Only an `Exit Function` or `End Function` can do that (Or an error).

This is what you are doing wrong.  Assigning the function and returning are entirely separate actions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not exactly sure why this assumption was so thoroughly engrained in my head. Predictably, adding `Exit Function` does fix both problems.